# Changing the content of Pickle File

Tags: python, pickle

I have trained a deep learning model and it got saved in a pickle file.  Due to some reason, I have to slightly change the code from which I got the pickle file. It took me months in training & I want to anyhow use the last pickle file created, as the weights will remains same. Is there any way to view and change the content of the pickle file?

Edit: For example, if we have the stylegan2 pre-trained network pickle file and suppose we made changes on the G_synthesis function code (present in https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2/blob/master/training/networks_stylegan2.py) then how can we use the old pickled file.

Comment: The question is extremely unclear; however you can always `pickle.load` it to see what's inside it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Take, for example, the stylegan2 pre-trained network pickle file. Suppose you made changes on the G_synthesis function (present in https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2/blob/master/training/networks_stylegan2.py) then how can you use the old pickled file. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: That's clearer. (you can [edit] the question to add that)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I made the changes,  now you can take your downvote back as well if put any :) :), as this question can help many.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change some functions but keep the same weights, can you just copy the weights to new model like this:

```py
import pickle
from old_model_file import old_model
from new_model_file import new_model

# 1.load pickle file
with open('old.pickle','rb') as f:
    old_pickle = pickle.load(f)

# 2.create model based new model
new_pickle = new_model()

# 3. copy weights from old model 
'''
##you should copy all weights from old_pickle to new_pickle
##for example:
new_pickle.weight_A = old_pickle.weight_A
new_pickle.weight_B = old_pickle.weight_B
'''

# 4. save the new model
with open('new.pickle','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(new_pickle,f)
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. I'm not much confident about how the pickle file gets loaded and what gets stored inside the pickle file. But, isn't it possible to change the pickle file content itself, Although your method should work fine as well?

Comment: I think that it's impossible to change the pickle file content itself. For the file load part, it depends on the method that you save this file. In my case above, old_model and new_model are class, and pickle file is just save using dump, so I can load like that. But it's not important, what's important is the idea to get your purpose: 1. load old_pickle 2. create new_pickle 3. copy weights from old_pickle to new_pickle 4. save the new_pickle